# Trying to return a function specific to DOM input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been challenging myself to create a function that keeps the global variable environment as unpolluted as possible and after lots of 'breakthroughs' (this is a new and challenging topic for me) I feel like I've hit a wall and am starting to get burned out.

My current aim is to have the `formMaths(formula)` take an argument representing either the HTML input's `multiply` or `divide` value, check it against the conditionals, and then return the appropriate higher-order function and callback.

Good new is I am able to get the formula to work. The bad news is that it only returns the output of whatever is in the first condition of the function. I have tried setting up parameters for the formMaths in the `onClick` attribute, inserted DOM related commands, etc ... no luck so far.

Getting to this point has been a journey and I've tried several different approaches but they all seem to come short. I feel like I am almost there, but I've felt that for a while now. I would love to see what is needed to complete this function as well as any improvements that can be made on the code.

Thank you!

```
<body>
    <form>
    1st Number: <input type="text" id="firstNum"></br>
    2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNum"></br>
    <input type="button" value="multiply" onClick="formMaths()">
    <input type="button" value="divide" onClick="formMaths()">
    <p>The result is: <span id="result"></span></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<script>
    function formMaths(formula) {
        let multiAB = (a,b) => {
            return a * b;
        }

        let divideAB = (a,b) => {
            return (a / b);
        }

        function doMaths(callback) {
            let firstNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
            let secondNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = callback(firstNum, secondNum);
        }

        if (formula = 'multiply') return doMaths(multiAB);
        else if (formula = 'divide') return doMaths(divideAB);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to check which button was clicked on, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to check which function was clicked and then return the appropriate output.

Comment: No worries @Kevin I have the solution, will write an answer now.

Comment: I've answered @Kevin, does this fix your problem?

Comment: @JackBashford It did! A nice crisp solution, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an argument into your `formMaths()` calls like so:

```
onclick="formMaths(this.id)"
```

Because here `this` corresponds to the button clicked, and `id` the ID of the button (`multiply`/`divide`), this will work in your favour and make `formula` work:

```js
function formMaths(formula) {
  let multiAB = (a, b) => {
    return a * b;
  }

  let divideAB = (a, b) => {
    return a / b;
  }

  function doMaths(callback) {
    let firstNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
    let secondNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = callback(firstNum, secondNum);
  }

  if (formula == 'multiply') return doMaths(multiAB);
  else if (formula == 'divide') return doMaths(divideAB);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    1st Number: <input type="text" id="firstNum"><br> 
    2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNum"><br>
    <input type="button" value="multiply" id="multiply" onclick="formMaths(this.id)">
    <input type="button" value="divide" id="divide" onclick="formMaths(this.id)">
    <p>The result is: <span id="result"></span></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

The second thing I fixed was in your `if` statements - you were using only 1 equals sign. This was making your maths multiply every time since you were setting `formula` to `multiply`, not testing it. I changed it to 2 equals signs, and now it works.